# FTP Entire Directory using PHP with recursive function

Tags: php, ftp

I am working on a code that will upload a folder of update files to several websites.  I have been trying to get the following function to upload all files and folders to the FTP account. In this case the local folder containing the files is named "files" and all documents are being uploaded to the parent directory of the ftp account.

**Function**

```
function upload_dir($dirname,$conn_id) {
    $dir_array=array();
   if (is_dir($dirname))
      $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
   if (!$dir_handle)
      return false;
   while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
         if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file)){
             $dirname2= str_replace('files','',$dirname);
             if($dirname2[0]=='/'){
                $dirname2 = substr($dirname2, 1);
             }
             ftp_put($conn_id, $dirname2."/".$file, $dirname."/".$file, FTP_BINARY);
         }
         else{
             $dirname2= str_replace('files','',$dirname);
             if($dirname2[0]=='/'){
                  $dirname2 = substr($dirname2, 1);
             }

             if(in_array($dirname2.'/'.$file, $dir_array)){
                 upload_dir($dirname.'/'.$file,$conn_id);
             }
             else{
                 array_push($dir_array, $dirname2.'/'.$file);
                 // check if directory exists before trying to create it
                    $filename = $dirname2.'/'.$file;
                    if (file_exists($filename)) {
                    } else {
                      ftp_mkdir($conn_id,$dirname2.'/'.$file);
                    }
                 upload_dir($dirname.'/'.$file,$conn_id);
             }
         }
      }
   }
   closedir($dir_handle);
   return true;
}
```

**Code**

```
// Ftp All data to new server
$ftp_server = "ftp.mywebsite.com";
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 
// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'password'); 
// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
$reply  = "FTP connection has failed!";
$reply .= "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user zerozill@".$option1; 
exit; 
} else {
$reply = "Connected to $ftp_server, for user annon";
upload_dir('files',$conn_id);
}
// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

The issue I am having is that the function works for the most part but for some reason it refuses to upload folders at times.  For example I have a folder named scripts. Every time I run this function it will not upload the scripts folder.  As well it still tries to upload all the files to the folder creating errors that the scripts folder does not exist. I dont know if I am overlooking something or what but any help with this matter is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe check to see if your upload script has the correct permissions? Maybe check to see if the scripts folder and the destination location also have correct permissions to be read and written, respectively (if you're using Linux, do `ls -l` in the shell to see).

Comment: So it uploads entire folders some of the time, but not all of time?  Or some folders, but not others?  (Just wrapping my head around it).

Comment: I have already checked all permissions and everything is set properly by default all folders are set to 755 and all other folders are uploading properly.

Comment: It uploads entire folders and sub directories most of the time but in the case of "scripts" it completely ignores creating the folder.

Comment: The Pear NET_FTP package makes this type of thing much easier, just as an fyi. http://pear.php.net/package/Net_FTP/redirected

Comment: The issue with Pear NET_FTP is that it will not upload .htaccess files for some odd reason.

Comment: Two questions.  1.  What ftp server are you uploading to.  Could the server have a configuration that disallows creation of certain folder names.  2. What OS on server.  Ubuntu, for example, has some security software called AppArmor that ships with a largish set of default security policies.  One of them might be creation of a folder named scripts.  These restrictions can be app by app, such that you ftp server might be restricted, where no such restriction would exist if you were shelled into the server.

Comment: I took dethtron5000's suggestion and went with NET_FTP and managed to get the .htaccess files to write properly.